# How to add a title in the table of contents slide in r markdown Beamer

Tags: latex, r-markdown, beamer

In R Markdown Beamer, I included a Table of Contents (TOC) via this command:

```
output: 
  beamer_presentation: 
    toc: true
    slide_level: 2
```

[image: Slide to be inserted the title]

I need a way to make a title for the slide of TOC (and in Portuguese). I have seen some answered questions, but they were not for Beamer.

Answer (score 4):

You could manually insert the toc, then you have full control of the frametitle:

```
---
output: 
  beamer_presentation: 
    slide_level: 2
    keep_tex: true

---

## outline
\tableofcontents[hideallsubsections]

# sec 1

# sec 2
```

[image]